# Select not working properly

Tags: c, linux

In my application, when alarm fires, i write an integer to a pipe from the signal handler. 
In my main application, i forever loop on select() with 0 timeout value. 
The problem is that signal handler successfully writes to the write end of the pipe, but select NEVER shows that readability of the read end of the pipe. So in the below pseudo code , return value from select would be 0.
Even what is more preplexing is that if i remove select and simply do a blocking read(), it works!!! i can read the integer written by the handler. It is just that select always think that the read end of the pipe is not readable and hence always return 0.

So pseduo code looks like

```
int x=0;
for(;;)
{

   x = select(maxfd, &readfd, NULL, NULL, &dontWait); // dontWait is timeval with tv_sec and tv_usec = 0
    if (x == 1)
     //check for read descriptor and do something
}
```

Comment: I never thought I'd get to use this when someone actually said `select` is broken: [Select is not broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: @BrianRoach it is more of a English language issue. After working on this problem for few hours, into late hours, i couldnt really think of a better title than my select is not working. What i really meant was my usage of select in my context and certainly not that select is broken

Comment: Sorry, it was meant to be more in jest / joking than anything else. I meant no offense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `select` function will *modify* both the sets and the timeout. You have to re-initialize the descriptor sets and timeout each iteration of the loop before the `select` call.

Also, you shouldn't really use `if (x == 1)`, but use the `if (FD_ISSET(some_fd, &readfd))`. And remember that `maxfd` should be the max filedescriptor used in any set *plus one*.

Comment: Thank you, by re-initializing the descriptor sets, the problem is solved!!! What is rationale behind re-initlizing the descriptor sets?

Comment: @Jimm The `select` function modifies its arguments.

Answer (score 1):

`select` works on `fd_set`s. It appears you are trying to pass a pointer to a descriptor (an int) to select?

I suggest consulting the man page for `select` and `fd_set`:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/fd_set